# Why My Provisioning Profiles are active in dev apples site and inactive in Xcode?

Tags: xcode4, provisioning

Can't attach screenshots because I has no 10 reputation.
But in my iOS Provisioning Portal I have status of all my Provision Profiles - "Active". When I'm downloading them and installing in Xcode they get status "Valid signing identity not found". Why?

P.S. I think it's because during creating my App ID I had to use my Team ID as Bundle Seed ID. But I have no any drop down menu to choose another one. I have only text: "Your Team ID (IDIDIDIDID) will be used as the App ID Prefix." (I changed my ID to IDIDIDIDID).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are attempting to build iOS apps from a brand new machine instead of the machine that your original certificates were built on.

You need to export your public & private keys from the original machine and import them into the keychain on your new machine.  Look for the ones that say "iPhone Developer:" and "iPhone Distribution:".  You can use the "Keychain Access" app in the `/Application/Utilities` folder to do this.

Comment: I have only 1 machine (iMac) and private/public keys are on it.

Comment: If that's the case, it sounds like you may have to re-generate your keys and certificates then. Hopefully you do not have too many profiles to re-generate.

Comment: I'm just started to learn Xcode, so I have only test works. But I have regenerated my certificate and keys and provision profiles 2 times. It's doesn't help me...